# Play the selected song on a different activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

This is where I retrieve the list of all the songs in the storage:

`enter code here`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public static final long pos=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView audioView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.songView);

    ArrayList<String> audioList = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION};// Can include more data for more details and check it.

    final Cursor audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);

    if(audioCursor != null){
        if(audioCursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                int audioIndex = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);

                audioList.add(audioCursor.getString(audioIndex));
            }while(audioCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    audioCursor.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, audioList);
    audioView.setAdapter(adapter);

    audioView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            Intent now_play=new Intent(MainActivity.this, NowPlaying.class);
            now_play.putExtra(pos, id);
            startActivity(now_play);
        }
    }
```

}

How do I make the intent pass which song has been selected and then how do I make this code play that file?

```
public class NowPlaying extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private ImageButton bplay;
private ImageButton bpause;
private ImageButton bfr;
private ImageButton bff;
private ImageButton breplay;
MediaPlayer mp;
SeekBar sb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.now_playing);
    initializeVariables();

    bplay.setOnClickListener(this);
    bpause.setOnClickListener(this);
    bff.setOnClickListener(this);
    bfr.setOnClickListener(this);

    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progress=0;

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            this.progress=progress;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    breplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    }

}
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v) {
        case id.play:
            mp.start();
            break;
        case id.pause:
            mp.pause();
            break;
        case id.ff:
            mp.reset();
}
```

}
    private void initializeVariables() {

```
    bplay=(ImageButton)findViewById(id.play);
    bff=(ImageButton)findViewById(id.ff);
    bfr= (ImageButton) findViewById(id.fr);
    bpause=(ImageButton)findViewById(id.pause);
    breplay=(ImageButton)findViewById(id.replay);
    mp=new MediaPlayer();
    sb=(SeekBar)findViewById(id.seekBar);
}
```

}

Comment: just dont downvote it. I will edit it if it in any way does not conform to the standards of stack.

Answer (score 1):

> Play the selected song on a different activity

Get `URI` of selected song then pass to to next Activity in which want to play.

Do it as:

**1.** Use `Audio.Media.DATA` to get path of song files in same way as getting `DISPLAY_NAME`:

```
ArrayList<String> audioFilePathList = new ArrayList<>();
String path =audioCursor.getString(audioCursor.getColumnIndex(Audio.Media.DATA));
audioFilePathList.add(path);
```

**2.** In  `onItemClick` method use `position` for getting selected item file path from `audioFilePathList`:

```
String strSelectedPath=audioFilePathList.get(position);
now_play.putExtra(pos, id);
now_play.putExtra("file_path", strSelectedPath);
startActivity(now_play);
```

**3.** In `NowPlaying` class get file path from Intent and pass it to `MediaPlayer` for play :

```
String file_path = getIntent().getStringExtra("file_path");
```

**how to play an audio file inside the raw folder using create**

Do it as:

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(NowPlaying.this, R.raw.soundfilename);
mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: I have another problem which I forgot to mention:
"now_play.putExtra(pos, id);" is showing the error: cannot resolve method putExtra(long, long).

Comment: @SidharthKriplani: For other issue if possible ask a new question instead of editing current. let me know what it is

Comment: Also, I just know how to play an audio file inside the raw folder using create. So can you tell the step after the 3rd one because I have no idea how I will do it here..

Comment: @SidharthKriplani: see my answer probably help you

Comment: But this is that same way of storing an audio file inside the raw folder and then playing it. Here, I want the MediaPlayer to play the song which the user selected. I dont think this will work will it?

Answer (score 0):

The error in your position can be simple fixed by the following code:

```
now_play.putExtra("pos",id)
```